# how to increase azure searching performance

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cognitive-search

I am new to Azure services. In my project 
there is a function to search text words or multiple text words. For example, if I search "best phase", the search should return data that are related "best" and "phase" in my data.

Sample example code below. Note: `searchParameters` is used to sort and order my data by their date

```
string searchText = "best phase";
string[] temp = searchText.Contains(" ") ? searchText.Split(' ') : new string[] { searchText};

var documentSearch = _indexClient.Documents.Search("\"" + searchText + "\"^2, \"|" + searchText + "|\", +" + searchText + ", +" + string.Join(", +", temp)  , searchParameters);
```

The current implementation consumes too much time at around 15-20 sec or more. So I need to do searches faster. Any idea how to make it faster :-)

Comment: What pricing tier are you using (Free, Basic, Standard, etc.)?

Comment: dear @Bruce Johnston sorry for the delay this azure is standard

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your search text. Please email me at bruce dot johnston at Microsoft and provide your search service name, region, and the approximate date/time of the slow search requests. Thanks!

Comment: hello @BruceJonston I think this problem comes form indexes are not updated but when we update indexes there is some good result and results are getting fast . but for that, we have to update indexes daily

Comment: The freshness of the index should have no impact on performance, only on the relevance of your search results. If you continue having performance issues, feel free to contact me (I left my details in the comment above).

Answer (score 3):

You can use Azure Search as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers).

You can also use Full-Text Search of SQL Azure as explained [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/full-text-search-is-now-available-for-preview-in-azure-sql-database/).

To decide which one to use, please read the difference between them on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-what-is-azure-search#how-it-compares) article.

Hope this helps.

Comment: dear sir @Alberto Morillo thanks for replay in here am using MVC application  here I am searching like "best phase" where it should match related all term like math "best phase" , "best" , "phase" (all exact match and text match phase) I think in my code I am sending more condition to get result so it may be slow for that reason ?